# How can i measure the overhead due to task migration/load balancing on linux with the real time patch?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time

I am trying to measure the overhead due to task migration. by overhead i would like to measure the latency involved in such a an activity. I know there are separate run queues available for each core and the kernel periodically checks the run queues to check whether there is a imbalance and wakes up a kernel thread ( perhaps a higher priority ) that does the migration.

Could any one provide me with pointers to kernel source code where i can insert time stamps to measure this value?

Is there any other performance metric which i probably investigate to get such an overhead?

Answer (score 0):

I remember there is a post before that discussed about this topic, and someone also posted some codes about how to get the system overhead.

I see you want to add some codes to insert time stamps, do you think it's feasible because task schedule is so frequent. I think you can follow the topic that posted before.

I ever saved the source codes from the post, thanks for the author!

```C
double getCurrentValue() {
    double percent;
    FILE* file;
    unsigned long long totalUser, totalUserLow, totalSys, totalIdle, total;

    file = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    fscanf(file, "cpu %Ld %Ld %Ld %Ld", &totalUser, &totalUserLow,
        &totalSys, &totalIdle);
    fclose(file);

    if (totalUser < lastTotalUser || totalUserLow < lastTotalUserLow ||
        totalSys < lastTotalSys || totalIdle < lastTotalIdle) {
        //Overflow detection. Just skip this value.
        percent = -1.0;
    }
    else {
        total = (totalUser - lastTotalUser) + (totalUserLow - lastTotalUserLow) +
            (totalSys - lastTotalSys);
        percent = total;
        total += (totalIdle - lastTotalIdle);
        percent /= total;
        percent *= 100;
    }

    lastTotalUser = totalUser;
    lastTotalUserLow = totalUserLow;
    lastTotalSys = totalSys;
    lastTotalIdle = totalIdle;

    return percent;
}
```